# Provider in different route - Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, authentication, firebase-authentication

I'm new in Flutter development, i'm making an app with Firebase Auth, in where I'm using an Authentication Wrapper class that, if user is logged in, goes to Home Screen, else goes to SignIn Screen.

The problem is that, when I want to navigate to AuthWrapper, I get this error message in a red screen:

```
Error: Could not find the correct Provider<UserFirebaseModel> above this Builder Widget

This happens because you used a `BuildContext` that does not include the provider
of your choice. There are a few common scenarios:

- You added a new provider in your `main.dart` and performed a hot-reload.
  To fix, perform a hot-restart.

- The provider you are trying to read is in a different route.

  Providers are "scoped". So if you insert of provider inside a route, then
  other routes will not be able to access that provider.

- You used a `BuildContext` that is an ancestor of the provider you are trying to read.

  Make sure that Builder is under your MultiProvider/Provider<UserFirebaseModel>.
  This usually happens when you are creating a provider and trying to read it immediately.
```

Here there are the most important classes of my code, where I think the problem is.

**main.dart**

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamProvider.value(
      value: Authentication().user,
      initialData: UserFirebaseModel.initialData(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'AccessCity',
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
          fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
        ),
        routes: getAppRoutes(),
        initialRoute: '/',
        onGenerateRoute: (RouteSettings settings) {
          return MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (BuildContext context) => HomeTempPage(),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**authWrapper.dart**

```
class AuthWrapper extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final user = Provider.of<UserFirebaseModel>(context);
    print(user);

    // ignore: unnecessary_null_comparison
    if (user == null) {
      return LoginPage();
    } else {
      return Home();
    }
  }
}
```

**routes.dart**

```
Map<String, WidgetBuilder> getAppRoutes() {
  return <String, WidgetBuilder>{
    // Home Temporal Page
    '/': (BuildContext context) => HomeTempPage(),

    // Components Pages
    'generalBigButton': (BuildContext context) => GeneralBigButtonPage(),
    'textEntryField': (BuildContext context) => TextEntryFieldPage(),
    'secureTextEntryField': (BuildContext context) =>
        SecureTextEntryFieldPage(),
    'underlinedButton': (BuildContext context) => UnderlinedButtonPage(),

    // Modules
    'login': (BuildContext context) => LoginPage(),

    'authWrapper': (BuildContext context) => AuthWrapper(),
  };
}
```

**homeTempPage.dart**

```
const String _title = 'Home Temporal';
const String _goAccessCityButton = 'Ir a AccessCity';
const String _goAccessCityLabel = 'Ir a pantalla Login de la app';

class HomeTempPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeTempPageState createState() => _HomeTempPageState();
}

class _HomeTempPageState extends State<HomeTempPage> {
  final model = HomeTempModel();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(_title),
        backgroundColor: mainBlue,
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            SizedBox(height: 10),
            MaterialButton(
              child: Text(_goAccessCityButton),
              color: Colors.blue,
              textColor: Colors.white,
              onPressed: () {
                model.navigateToStart(context);
              },
            ),
            Text(_goAccessCityLabel),
            SizedBox(height: 30),
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                child: ListView(
                  children: model.getComponents(context),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

In this last class, the line

> navigateToStart() method

goes to route 'authWrapper'.

**UserFirebaseModel**

```
class UserFirebaseModel {
  final String id;
  final String email;

  UserFirebaseModel(this.id, this.email);

  factory UserFirebaseModel.initialData() {
    return UserFirebaseModel('', '');
  }
}
```

**Authentication class**

```
class Authentication {
  final FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  // Create user based on User (ex FirebaseUser)
  UserFirebaseModel? _userFromFirebaseUser(User? user) {
    final _mail;
    if (user != null) {
      _mail = user.email;
      if (_mail != null) {
        return UserFirebaseModel(user.uid, _mail);
      }
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }

  // Auth change user stream
  Stream<UserFirebaseModel?> get user {
    return _firebaseAuth.authStateChanges().map(_userFromFirebaseUser);
  }

  // Sign in with email and password
  Future<String?> signIn({
    required String email,
    required String password,
  }) async {
    try {
      await _firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: email,
        password: password,
      );
      print("Signed in");
      return "";
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      return e.message;
    }
  }

  User? getUser() {
    try {
      return _firebaseAuth.currentUser;
    } on FirebaseAuthException {
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks for your help, i need to solve it!

Comment: What is your `UserFirebaseModel` definition and where do you create this provider?

Comment: @PeterKoltai I edited the post, adding UserFirebaseModel class and Authentication class, where provider is created

Comment: Please check this [guide](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple). For `UserFirebaseModel` class to work as a notifier, you must declare it like `class UserFirebaseModel extends ChangeNotifier` and do a lot of other stuff.